# putting words of a sentence into different transparent labels when a button is clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsmutablestring

i have a sentence which i stored in a NSMutablesstring, i have a button such that when tapped, it loads the sentence words into labels, for example, take "i am a boy" for instance, when the button is clicked, it loads "i" into a label, "am" into another label, "a" in another label and "boy" in another label.

Comment: What are you asking...?

Comment: @David separating words of a sentence and putting them into labels when a button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *sentence = @"i am a boy";
NSMutableArray *words = [sentence componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

CGFloat xVal = 0.0;

for( NSString *word in words ) {

    UILabel *wordLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xVal,0,200,40)];
    wordLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    wordLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    wordLabel.text  = word;
    xVal+=200;

    [self.view addSubview:wordLabel];
}
```

Comment: this didnt work, the application crashes when i click the button that contains this method

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray* labels = [@"i am a boy" componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
CGFloat xOffset = 0.0;
for NSString *labeltext in labels
   UILabel *wordLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOffset,0,300,40)];
   wordLabel.text  = word;
   xOffset+=200;
   [self.view addSubview:wordLabel];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split "I am a boy" into array.

```
NSString* example = @"I am a boy";
NSArray *arr = [example componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
          [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "]];
```

Then, you can set Text to UILabel

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSString